# Calculating determinants. Help appreciated

Tags: calculus, determinant

Does anyone know how I would go about answering this question? Any feedback is appreciated. I'm not too sure where to start.

> (a) Calculate the determinant of $D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and use it to find $D^{-1}$.
>   (b) Verify that $$ I = DD^{-1} = D^{-1}D. $$
>   (c) By using $D^{-1}$ obtained from part (a), solve the following system of linear equations:
>   \begin{align*} x_1 + 2x_2 &= a\\ 2x_1 - x_2 &= b\end{align*}where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint of (a).**
$$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} =\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\-c&a \end{pmatrix} $$
and $\det \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}=ad-bc.$

**Hint of (c).** Every systems of linear equations is can be expressed as $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, where $A$ is matrix and $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{b}$ are column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

(a) What is the definition of determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix? $D^{-1}$ is $\frac1{\det(D)}$ times what matrix?

(b) Perform the matrix multiplications specified.

(c) You can rewrite that system of equations as $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\2 & -1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\right]$$ How can you use what you found out in part (b) to solve for $x_1,x_2$?